# In MongoDB mapreduce, how can I flatten the values object?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I'm trying to use MongoDB to analyse Apache log files. I've created a `receipts` collection from the Apache access logs. Here's an abridged summary of what my models look like:

```
db.receipts.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4e57908c7a044a30dc03a888"),
    "path" : "/videos/1/show_invisibles.m4v",
    "issued_at" : ISODate("2011-04-08T00:00:00Z"),
    "status" : "200"
}
```

I've written a [MapReduce function](https://gist.github.com/1183561) that groups all data by the `issued_at` date field. It summarizes the total number of requests, and provides a breakdown of the number of requests for each unique path. Here's an example of what the output looks like:

```
db.daily_hits_by_path.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2011-04-08T00:00:00Z"),
    "value" : {
        "count" : 6,
        "paths" : {
            "/videos/1/show_invisibles.m4v" : {
                "count" : 2
            },
            "/videos/1/show_invisibles.ogv" : {
                "count" : 3
            },
            "/videos/6/buffers_listed_and_hidden.ogv" : {
                "count" : 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make the output look like this instead:

```
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2011-04-08T00:00:00Z"),
    "count" : 6,
    "paths" : {
        "/videos/1/show_invisibles.m4v" : {
            "count" : 2
        },
        "/videos/1/show_invisibles.ogv" : {
            "count" : 3
        },
        "/videos/6/buffers_listed_and_hidden.ogv" : {
            "count" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not currently possible, but I would suggest voting for this case: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2517.

Comment: This is the right answer, so vote for this case and then use http://stackoverflow.com/a/18124090/1402121 as your solution

Answer (score 7):

Taking the best from previous answers and comments:

```
db.items.find().hint({_id: 1}).forEach(function(item) {
    db.items.update({_id: item._id}, item.value);
});
```

From http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#replace-existing-document-with-new-document
"If the `update` argument contains only field and value pairs, the `update()` method replaces the existing document with the document in the `update` argument, except for the `_id` field."

So you need neither to `$unset value`, nor to list each field.

From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#cursor-snapshot
"MongoDB cursors can return the same document more than once in some situations. ... use a unique index on this field or these fields so that the query will return each document no more than once. Query with hint() to explicitly force the query to use that index."

Comment: This leads to serious race conditions.

Comment: @DerekBrown, please explain or provide a proof or point to the bug in this code

Comment: `db.items.update()` is asynchronous, so the execution of the external call (ie `db.items.find().hint()....foreach()`) can terminate before all of the updates have been performed.

Comment: @DerekBrown, the code above uses standard synchronous JS API. If you use asynchronous driver, then it is your responsibility to wait for all async operations to complete.
If you wanted to say that update is eventually consistent (which is not the same as asynchronous), and default write concern is not enough for your case, then please use more strict write concern configuration - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/

Comment: 1) The synchronous driver isn't officially supported.  So at the very least you should mention that your code requires you use a different mongo driver.

2) Write Concern isn't relevant here.  The problem isn't that the updates you have created aren't propagating to other shards, but that future queries (which require the updates be completed) have not yet been issued on the single instance that NodeJS is interacting with.

Comment: @DerekBrown, MongoDB Manual https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/ and all the answers to this post use synchronous JS API, unless noted otherwise, like one "Java example" in this post. If you are using Node.js async driver, then you really need to `await col.update` as in http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/reference/ecmascriptnext/crud/#updating-documents This post is about MongoDB, not about Node.js driver for MongoDB.

Comment: @DerekBrown, MongoDB Manual https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/ and all the answers to this post use synchronous JS API, unless noted otherwise, like one "Java example" in this post. If you are using Node.js async driver, then you really need to `await col.update` as in http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/reference/ecmascriptnext/crud/#updating-documents This post is about MongoDB, not about Node.js driver for MongoDB.

Comment: I mean, yes the post is about MongoDB, but your answer is in Node.JS and is incorrect.  Also- `await` is probably not the best, you should use `Promise.map()` or a Bulk Update.

Comment: @DerekBrown, My answer is NOT in Node.JS! My answer uses synchronous JS API of MongoDB, like most other answers here do. `Node.JS != any other JS`. Yes, in any async environment it is reasonable to await all updates at once, not each one separately, but this is out of scope of my answer, because it is NOT in Node.JS!

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, by design Mongo's map reduce will spit results out in "value tuples" and I haven't seen anything that will configure that "output format". Maybe the finalize() method can be used.

You could try running a post-process that will reshape the data using

```
results.find({}).forEach( function(result) {
  results.update({_id: result._id}, {count: result.value.count, paths: result.value.paths})
});
```

Yep, that looks ugly. I know.

Comment: is there not a way to modify the `result` object/document directly?

Answer (score 4):

You can do Dan's code with a collection reference:

```
    function clean(collection) { 
      collection.find().forEach( function(result) {
      var value = result.value;
      delete value._id;     
      collection.update({_id: result._id}, value);     
      collection.update({_id: result.id}, {$unset: {value: 1}} ) } )};
```

Answer (score 3):

A similar approach to that of @ljonas but no need to hardcode document fields:

```js
db.results.find().forEach( function(result) {
    var value = result.value;
    delete value._id;
    db.results.update({_id: result._id}, value);
    db.results.update({_id: result.id}, {$unset: {value: 1}} )
} );
```

Answer (score 3):

All the proposed solutions are far from optimal. The fastest you can do so far is something like:

```
var flattenMRCollection=function(dbName,collectionName) {
    var collection=db.getSiblingDB(dbName)[collectionName];

    var i=0;
    var bulk=collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    collection.find({ value: { $exists: true } }).addOption(16).forEach(function(result) {
        print((++i));
        //collection.update({_id: result._id},result.value);

        bulk.find({_id: result._id}).replaceOne(result.value);

        if(i%1000==0)
        {
            print("Executing bulk...");
            bulk.execute();
            bulk=collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
        }
    });
    bulk.execute();
};
```

Then call it:
`flattenMRCollection("MyDB","MyMRCollection")`

This is WAY faster than doing sequential updates.

Comment: NB: this is new in MongoDB 2.6

Answer (score 0):

While experimenting with Vincent's answer, I found a couple of problems. Basically, if you perform updates within a foreach loop, this will move the document to the end of the collection and the cursor will reach that document again ([example](https://www.quora.com/How-did-mongodb-return-duplicated-but-different-documents)). This can be circumvented if [$snapshot](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/snapshot/) is used. Hence, I am providing a Java example below.

```
final List<WriteModel<Document>> bulkUpdate = new ArrayList<>();

// You should enable $snapshot if performing updates within foreach
collection.find(new Document().append("$query", new Document()).append("$snapshot", true)).forEach(new Block<Document>() {
    @Override
    public void apply(final Document document) {
        // Note that I used incrementing long values for '_id'. Change to String if
        // you used string '_id's
        long docId = document.getLong("_id");
        Document subDoc = (Document)document.get("value");
        WriteModel<Document> m = new ReplaceOneModel<>(new Document().append("_id", docId), subDoc);
        bulkUpdate.add(m);

        // If you used non-incrementing '_id's, then you need to use a final object with a counter.
        if(docId % 1000 == 0 && !bulkUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdate);
            bulkUpdate.removeAll(bulkUpdate);
        }
    }
});
// Fixing bug related to Vincent's answer.
if(!bulkUpdate.isEmpty()) {
    collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdate);
    bulkUpdate.removeAll(bulkUpdate);
}
```

Note : This snippet takes an average of 7.4 seconds to execute on my machine with 100k records and 14 attributes (IMDB dataset). Without batching, it takes an average of 25.2 seconds.