# copying attributes in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

So I have a collection in mongo with `created_at` fields, and I'm trying to add a `sort_date` attribute to each document, which will initially be equal to the `created_at` but modifiable by the user.  I'm using Mongoid with Rails and trying to write a migration, and I'm wondering if there's a clever (read: *efficient*) way to copy the value of one attribute to another without mapReduce or looping through the models in Ruby.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Answering my own question:*

Sadly, this seems to be the best option right now.  At least it's simpler than mapReduce, I suppose.  Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257989/in-mongodb-mapreduce-how-can-i-flatten-the-values-object/7258400#7258400).

```
db.mycoll.find({}).forEach(function(doc){
  db.mycoll.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {sort_date: doc.created_at}});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Please note that there are no migrations needed when you use MongoDB -- migrations are only needed for SQL DBs.

With MongoDB you can just change the attributes in your model, e.g.:

```
class YourCollection
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # add a field to your field definitions:
  field :sort_date , :Type => Time

end
```

... then create a script which you can use for initializing the data.

e.g.

```
YourCollection.each do |c|
  c.sort_date = c.created_a
  c.save(:validate => false)
end
```

If you need proper initialization for a new attribute, you could run a script in the console, or via Rake

See also: 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/238-mongoid

Comment: right - it is that second part i am referring to.  that would work, but as i said, im curious if it's possible to update all documents without looping through each one in ruby.  experimenting with doing it in mapReduce...

Comment: well, it's probably difficult to do, because each record contains a different value -- so unless you are on a parallel computer you'll have to touch each record sequentially -- and it doesn't matter if you could state that in nice looking syntax -- it would still have to be done sequentially -- unless you have a huge computing farm sitting around somewhere

Comment: if you use sharding in MongoDB, you could run this parallel on each shard -- that would be a small gain