# mongodb: How to avoid value.* after map/reduce

Tags: mongodb, format

After playing with mapreduce with mongoDB, I worry about the results having "two dimensions" instead of flat documents.

I.e. the documents look like {id:..., value:{test:123}}

Instead, I'd prefer this format: {...,test:123}

How to chose this style for the results/output collection?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: you can't (see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2517), see also similar StackOverflow questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574262/how-to-flat-result-after-mongodb-mapreduce and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257989/in-mongodb-mapreduce-how-can-i-flatten-the-values-object

Comment: I think the question then becomes: what is the fastest way to reformat the data into your desired format after a map/reduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output collection from a MongoDB map/reduce job will always have a top-level structure of

```
{_id: <something>, value: <something> }
```

That is, it will always be a document with two keys.  If you want to have the 'value' be a single value, you can do so by controlling your emit() and reduce() functions.

Here is an emit() function that will emit a single value for 'value':

```
emit() { this.date, 1 }
```

Here is a reduce() function that will return a single value for 'value':

```
reduce() {
  var count = 0;

  values.forEach(function(v) {
    count += v;
  });

  return count;
};
```

Remember: the "shape" of the document emitted by emit() ***MUST*** be the same as the one returned by reduce().

If you do this, the documents in the output collection will look something like this:

```
{ _id: ISODate("2012-11-27T00:27:41.103Z"), value: 99 }
```