# how to flat result after mongodb mapreduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

After playing with MapReduce with MongoDB,

The documents look like:

```
{_id: { somecola : 123, somecolb : 456 }, value:10 }
```

I want this format:

```
{ _id : somerandomcode, somecola : 123, somecolb : 456, value :10 }
```

Creating a new collection, and foreach + insert can do it but it is too slow, how to do it rapidly?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [In MongoDB mapreduce, how can I flatten the values object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257989/in-mongodb-mapreduce-how-can-i-flatten-the-values-object)

Comment: It's similar, but not actually a duplicate as this is in regards to the key, not the value.  But the answer is still the same -- no support for this currently.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Technically you are correct.  However the MR functions could easily be reformulated so that the key items are included with the value, e.g. {value: {somecola: 123, somecolb: 456, value: 10}}.  Hence the associated JIRA would fix both issues.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @mjhm Yep, totally agree. That JIRA does have the potential to address both key and value flattening.

Comment: Do you have to use map-reduce? if not you can achieve this using aggregation framework. project command can be used to rename fields of result set.

Comment: aggregation 's result limit size, so i have to use map-reduce.