# How do I remove the "value" in mapReduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I was wondering if it is possible to remove the "value" key in the map-reduce so that the final result just contains the values directly rather than being inside the "value" key.  I am looking to do it with just the commands (so no Javascript variables and such)

For example, the map-reduce output is typically

```
   [
           {
                   "_id" : 0,
                   "value" : {
                           "name" : "Apple",
                           "sold" : 1234
                   }
           },
           {
                   "_id" : 1,
                   "value" : {
                           "name" : "Amazon",
                           "sold" : 5678
                   }
           }
   ]
```

I would like it to end up as

```
   [
           {
                   "_id" : 0,
                   "name" : "Apple",
                   "sold" : 1234
           },
           {
                   "_id" : 1,
                   "name" : "Amazon",
                   "sold" : 5678
           }
   ]
```

I am thinking it can be done with the findAndModify command but I am not exactly sure how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In MongoDB mapreduce, how can I flatten the values object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257989/in-mongodb-mapreduce-how-can-i-flatten-the-values-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In MongoDB mapreduce, how can I flatten the values object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257989/in-mongodb-mapreduce-how-can-i-flatten-the-values-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not seems to be possible for now. There is a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2517) for that reported in Mongo.